# Sending user back to referring page

Tags: php, redirect

I am struggling to set up a redirection after successfully logging in by user.

The login page should redirect the user to the page where they were refused to access after they have successfully logged in.

For example, if a user clicks on 'My Account' before logging in (no session) then they are redirected to login page successfully but once they are logged in, how do I send them back to the "My Account" page?

Methods I tried include `$_SESSION['HTTP_REFERER]`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) is dangerous, since the referrer would be the same login page if the user received an error while trying to login (such as wrong password). You should store the back URL inside a session variable before redirecting the user to the login page, then, after they successfully log in, redirect them to the stored back URL.

For example, say you need to protect `page.php`, you could have something like this at the beginning of the file:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
    $_SESSION['backURL'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}
```

Then, after the user successfully logs in, you could populate the `$_SESSION['user']` variable then redirect to the URL you stored before sending him to the login page (or to the root of the site if it so happens that you don't have any back URL stored for whatever reason):

```
$backURL = empty($_SESSION['backURL']) ? '/' : $_SESSION['backURL'];
unset($_SESSION['backURL']);
header('Location: ' . $backURL);
exit;
```

Comment: This method worked, Thanks for help all who gave answers much appricated. Thanks once again Radu

Comment: It will be much better if you test $_SESSION['backURL']; because if someone bookmarked the login page and opens it directly, there will be an error. something like page not found...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
  header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
?>
```

Comment: I am aware. The OP asked specifically about "Sending user back to *referring* page" and the snippet does just that, which does not imply that this is what OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Have the page that does the redirecting set a session variable that is the URL of that page:

```
session_start();
if (!$logged_id)
{
    $_SESSION['redirect_url'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}
```

Then after a successful login redirect them to that URL:

```
session_start();

/* Login code goes here */

$redirect_url = (isset($_SESSION['redirect_url'])) ? $_SESSION['redirect_url'] : '/';
unset($_SESSION['redirect_url']);
header("Location: $redirect_url", true. 303);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
```

Will do it, but note:

You CANNOT output (`echo`,`print_r`,ect ect) anything before sending custom headers.

Comment: <?php
      header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
    ?>

tried above but does not work. keeps me on same page after logging in. The session is created successfully that means username and password was correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should remember last visited page in variable like `$_SESSION["last_page"]` (exclude login page). After user successfully was logged in, take value of variable and redirect user to his previous location.

You can't use referrer. For example, if user failed his first attempt to login, in second attempt his referer will be login page.

Another way is to authenticate user using ajax without separate login page. If login was successful, you can simply refresh page with javascript.